# Error in C++ time structures

Tags: c++, pointers, time, user-defined-functions

I am creating a program to save weather info of current day. After running the code, I get struct tm redefined error. I am running this in codeblocks using visual c++ 2008 as compiler

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>

struct tm  //date template
    {
        int tm_mday //day of month
        int tm_mon; //month of year
        int tm_year; //year
        //char date[11];
    };

    struct weather
    {
        struct tm *wdate1;
        int high_temp;
        int low_temp;
        int max_wind_speed;
        int preciption;
        char note[80];
    };


int main()
{
    time_t wdate;
    struct weather info[3];

    ctime(&wdate);

    printf("%s",wdate);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "After running the code" -> "After *compiling* the code". Big difference between a compile time error and a run-time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are redefining a structure which is already defined with the same name "tm" in time.h. If you trying to redefine this template with same structure name, then please do not import

```
 #include <time.h>
```

Also in the struct tm, you are missing a terminator after the tm_mday, and command

```
 printf("%s",wdate);
```

will result an in error as wdate is not a char *. You should club the last two lines as

```
 printf("%s",ctime(&wdate));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Slight modification, I suggest: `#include <ctime>`

Comment: @LeFlou : Yes, we have to include <ctime> mentioned in the std namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Redefining struct tm - like the error message says - is exactly what you are doing. The tm struct is defined in time.h. You are defining it again here in lines 5-11. You should remove this definition, or call it different if you want to define a custom struct for your own use.